# Counting Each Foor Loop

Tags: for-loop, indexing, counting

I am trying to write down a mob spawn script (wave style).

and this is what I came up with :

```
func _on_enemy_spawn_timer_timeout():
    var enemy1_count = get_node(".").get_child_count()
    var loop_count = 0
    if enemy1_count < 5 :
        loop_count = loop_count + 1
        for c in range(1):
            random_x.randomize()
            var random_x_number = random_x.randf_range(-20,20)
            random_y.randomize()
            var random_y_number = random_y.randf_range(1,1)
            random_z.randomize()
            var random_z_number = random_z.randf_range(-20,20)
            var gem_instance = preload ("res://sahneler/gem.tscn").instance()
            add_child(gem_instance)
            add_to_group("gems")
            gem_instance.set_translation(Vector3(random_x_number,random_y_number,random_z_number))
            print (enemy1_count)
        print (loop_count)
```

well this is works actualy, but there is a huge flaw in it, this code spawn enemies one by one (one enemy spawned every 0.5 second).

but after I kill one enemy, script fill the hole and spawn another one, make it 5 again.
but what I want is, control over how many enemy spawned in each wave.

for example, in this script, I wanna only 5 enemy spawned, after all of them killed, there will be new wave, and that wave will have 10 enemy etc.

I try to count each loop and try to break after 5 enemy spawned, but, it doesn't work. This is how it looks like:

[image: game_view]

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
var loop_count : int = 0
    
    
    func _on_enemy_spawn_timer_timeout():
        var enemy1_count = get_node(".").get_child_count()
        
    
    
        if enemy1_count < 5 :
            for c in range(1):
                if loop_count < 5:
                    loop_count += 1
                    random_x.randomize()
                    var random_x_number = random_x.randf_range(-20,20)
                    random_y.randomize()
                    var random_y_number = random_y.randf_range(1,1)
                    random_z.randomize()
                    var random_z_number = random_z.randf_range(-20,20)
                    var gem_instance = preload ("res://sahneler/gem.tscn").instance()
                    add_child(gem_instance)
                    add_to_group("gems")
                    gem_instance.set_translation(Vector3(random_x_number,random_y_number,random_z_number))
        #           print (enemy1_count)
                    print (loop_count)
                else:
                    break
```